# Could this word, there, be read both adjective and adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adjuncts

> i) What’s that *over there*?
>  ii) People can take their pets
>   *there*.
>  iii) I believe one of the boys *there* thinks I'm pretty.
>  (All three are from [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/))
>  iv) Let’s go and see the
>   pets *there*.

**Does *there* function as an adjective in [iii]?**
*Over there* in [i] seems to modify pronoun that; *there* in [ii] verb *take*. But in [iii], it is not that simple. Because I don’t find in dictionaries the word *there* is denoted as adjective, I hesitate to say *there* modifies the previous noun phrase. However it seems to functions like an adjective. In this case, do you say *there* functions as an adjective as a noun or adverb, or there is an omission, that is, is it the short form of ‘one of the boys who is there’?

**Could *there* be read both adjective and adverb in [iv]?**
When I add *there* in [iv], can it be interpreted ambiguous; that is, can *there* be read either an noun-modifier or adverbial adjunct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not understand any of these *theres* as adverbials, and I would not understand any preposition phrase for which they might stand as adverbials either.

- The *theres* i) and iii) are *pro-locatives*, adjectivals locating the head NP. These can all stand as complements to *BE*.

  > What's that **there/on the roof**?
  >   The object **is** there/on the roof.
  >
  > I believe one of the boys **there/at the table in the corner** thinks I'm pretty.
  >   The boys **are** there/at the table in the corner.
- *There* in ii) is a *pro-directive*, an object complement (rather than a modifier) of the verb *take*: it is the place where the pets end up as a result of the action of taking.

  > People can take their pets **there/to that park**.
  >   When they do so, the pets are **there/in that park**.
- iv) is, as you say, ambiguous, or perhaps *ambivalent* would be a better term: it could be taken to act both as the pro-directive subject complement of the verb *go* and as a pro-locative adjectival modifying *pets*. But it hardly matters, since either way it's the same place, and the same entities end up there!

Comment: Reading your answer, I remind reading in Random House “in or at that place”; “into or to that place”. Neither having majored English nor using it, nor study fully, I reiterate forgetting and reminding silly. Thank you.